# child selector in CSS,how do i target only the parent items and child items

Tags: css

It is a bit embarassing that I cant get my hear round the child selector.How do I target the parent list items in an items-list? I tried `div#container > ul li{color: red;}`  but it changed the color of the entire item list,I was just looking to change the color of the parent items.

Say I want to specify a red color for all the parent list items and blue for all the child list items,how do i go about doing it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
 div#container > ul li{  
   color: red;  

 }  
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">  
        <ul>  
            <li> Parent List Item  
                <ul>  
                    <li> Child List Item  </li>  
                </ul>  
            </li>  
            <li> Parent List Item </li>  
            <li> Parent List Item </li>  
            <li> Parent List Item </li>  
        </ul>  
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do:

```
 div#container ul li{  
   color: red;  
 }
 div#container ul li ul li{  
   color: blue;  
 }
```

or even better, assign a class to the ul:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
 ul.parentList li{  
   color: red;  
 }
 ul.childList li{  
   color: blue;  
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">  
        <ul class='parentList'>  
            <li> Parent List Item  
                <ul class='childList'>    
                    <li> Child List Item  </li>  
                </ul>  
            </li>  
            <li> Parent List Item </li>  
            <li> Parent List Item </li>  
            <li> Parent List Item </li>  
        </ul>  
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,the reason i asked this was because I thought it will only target the list-items of the ul that are direct children of div#container. I was confused when it changed the color of listitems in ul that was a direct child of an li item.Please correct me if im wrong

Comment: You are correct but it's children then inherit that setting. You can't stop inheritance, you can only override it with an actual value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
div#container > ul > li{color: red;}
```

I'm not sure but you'll still have to override child's color.

```
 div#container > ul > li > ul >li{color: black;}
```

Comment: sorry mate it didnt work,unless im doing something wrong,will check again

Comment: you must override child node color.

Answer (score 1):

div#container>ul>li {color: red;} for parent items.

div#container>ul>li>ul>li {color: blue;} for child items.

i'd suggest using some classes though

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 div#container ul li {  /*parent*/
   color: red;  
 } 
 div#container ul li ul li {  /*children*/
   color: black;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the child item back to black?

```
div#container ul li ul li{
    color:black;
}
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9wQD/)***

Or use classes on the `ul`

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9wQD/1/)***

Comment: Negging a 5 year old answer, not leaving a reason why...Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container li{ color: black; } /* Default <li> style */

#container > ul > li{ color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without adding classes in the following manner

First set the color red only for the parent

```
div#container > ul > li
{
color: red;
}
```

This selector says, reading from left to right: select the li who is the child of ul who is the child of div which has an attribute of id with a value of container, and set the color to red. At this point you will notice that everything has changed to red. The reason for this is that when you set the color of red to the parent li, the child ul and li inherit the color and this causes the color of the children to be red also. So you have to override this with as follows.

```
div#container > ul > li > ul > li
{
color: blue;
}
```

This selector says, reading from left to right: select the li who is the child of ul who is the child of li who is the child of ul who is the child of div which has an attribute of id with a value of container, and set the color to blue. This overrides the inhertiance.